# Как оправлять разные ajax c разных submit одной формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма с двумя кнопками. Как проверять какая кнопка нажата и в зависимости от этого отправлять разный ajax

```js
    $(document).on('submit','#form',function(){

  var _data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({  
         url: window.location.href,
         dataType: "html",
         type: "POST",  
         data: _data,
         success: function(_form){
         
         }
     });
     return false;
 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Если именно определять из события submit, тогда используя аналогичный вопрос с [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission), сделал [небольшой пример на fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vc60zweg/3/), вместо alert отправляйте свои ajax.

`html форма`

```
<form action="handler.php">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a1">1<Br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a2">2<Br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a3">3<Br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit2">
</form>
```

`javascript` (что бы работало не забываем подключить `jquery`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event ) { 
        //Получаем имя нажатой кнопки
        var name = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr('name');
        if (name == "submit1") {
            alert('Нажата первая кнопка');
        } else if (name == "submit2")
        {
            alert('Нажата вторая кнопка');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });

    //Здесь по нажатию на кнопку ставим атрибут, что нажата
    $("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true");    
    });
});
```

---

Как по мне выглядит немного костыльно, наверное правильнее слушать события на кнопках и выполнять действия при нажатии на них. [Пример на fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2cyvqcnx/2/)

`html форма` остается прежней

`javascript`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $($("form input[type=submit]")[0]).click(function(event) {
        alert('Первая кнопка')
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $($("form input[type=submit]")[1]).click(function(event) {
        alert('Вторая кнопка')
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

либо методом определения события по селектору.
либо перепиши функцию на событие 'click' которое будет проверять элемент, связанный с данным событием. На пример:

```
    $('.button').on('click', function(){
      var curElem = $(this).attr('id');
    if(curElem == 'butn1'){
     // to do
     }
    else if(curElem == 'butn2'){
    //to do
    }
    });
```

и кнопкам повесить class="button" или по аналогии.
вообще: раз используешь JQ, то можешь хоть кастомные атрибут (селекторы) вешать к тегам и на них применять обработку события.

Comment: это плохой ответ, распишите пожалуйста на конкретном примере автора, как он может определить какая кнопка нажата, т.е. непосредственно рабочий код.

Comment: @Alex,  "*на конкретном примере автора*" расписать не получится, по той простой причине, что на текущий момент автор дал абстрактный, а не конкретный пример. Можно только догадываться:  что там за две кнопки и по какому признаку к ним можно обращаться.

Comment: @Deonis да, на примере автора это сделать трудно.  подразумевалось, чтобы ответ не просто содержал `if else`, а был бы хоть какой-то воспроизводимый пример как отличить какая кнопка нажата, чтобы автор мог от него отталкиваться.